# How to get PipelineOptions in composite PTransform in Beam 2.0?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

After upgrading to Beam 2.0 the `Pipeline` class doesn't have `getOptions()` class anymore.
I have a composite `PTransform` that relies on getting the options in the its `expand` method:

```
public class MyCompositeTransform extends PTransform<PBegin, PDone> {
    @Override
    public PDone expand(PBegin input) {
        Pipeline pipeline = input.getPipeline();
        MyPipelineOptions options = pipeline.getOptions().as(MyPipelineOptions.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

In Beam 2.0 there doesn't seem to be a way to access the `PipelineOptions` at all  in the `expand` method.

What's the alternative?

Answer (score 3):

[Pablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020492/4820657) is right on. I want to also clarify that there is a major change in how `PipelineOptions` are managed.

You can use them to parse and pass around the arguments to your `main` program (or whatever code builds your pipeline) but these are technically independent from the `PipelineOptions` that configure how your pipeline is run.

In Beam, the `Pipeline` is fully constructed, and only afterwards you choose a `PipelineRunner` and `PipelineOptions` to control how the pipeline is run. The pipeline itself does not actually have options.

If you do want the behavior of your `PTransform` (not its expansion) to use some option that is obtained dynamically, you should make your `PTransform` accept a `ValueProvider` [like this example in `WriteFiles`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/WriteFiles.java#L126) and you can define a pipeline option that returns a `ValueProvider` [like here in `ValueProviderTest`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/ValueProviderTest.java#L52)