# Dataflow DoFn will not serialize with PipelineOptions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to pass a PipelineOptions interface to a dataflow DoFn so that the DoFn can configure some unserializable things that it needs to reinstantiate, but it seems like Dataflow is unable to serialize the DoFn when I tell it to hold an instance of my PipelineOptions subclass. Is there something that I need to do to the Options interface to make it serialize correctly?

I know it is an option to write custom serialization + deserialization code (like in https://gist.github.com/jlewi/f1cd323dc88bd58601ef, [How to fix Dataflow unable to serialize my DoFn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032063/how-to-fix-dataflow-unable-to-serialize-my-dofn)), but it seems like the PipelineOptions class explicitly says that it should be serializable, and I would prefer to not to write serialization and deserialization code in every DoFn that I use this options object for.

Options class snippet:

```
public interface Options 
extends BigtableOptions, BigtableScanOptions, OfflineModuleOptions, Serializable {...}
```

DoFn definition

```
public class RunEventGeneratorsDoFn extends DoFn<...,...> {
    private OfflinePipelineRunner.Options options;
....
}
```

Serialization exception when Options is not marked `transient`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize [my DoFn]
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:54)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.clone(SerializableUtils.java:91)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$Bound.<init>(ParDo.java:720)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$Unbound.of(ParDo.java:678)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo$Unbound.access$000(ParDo.java:596)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo.of(ParDo.java:563)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.ParDo.of(ParDo.java:558)
    at [dofn instantiation line]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:50)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual pipeline options object should not be included as a field in a specific `DoFn` or `PTransform`. Instead, pass in the value of the specific options you want to access.

See this question for some more context "[How to get PipelineOptions in composite PTransform in Beam 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019815/how-to-get-pipelineoptions-in-composite-ptransform-in-beam-2-0/45024542#45024542)".